# How can i render a tiled map with C++/SDL

Tags: c++, dictionary, sdl

I want to render tiles to the screen from a text file. I have the random terrain generator working, and I can move the data from the text file to a 2d vector. What I'm having trouble with is understanding how to give those tiles the coordinates they need to be rendered at. How would I go about assigning each tile its own coordinates relative to the camera?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry that this may seem vague but I really have no idea where to start. I just kinda wanted to know what you would do if faced with this problem. Even just some resources on the subject would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest checking this lua [tutorial](http://www.forums.evilmana.com/lua-help/%28tutorial%29-how-to-make-a-platformer-basics-of-a-tile-engine/) on how create a tile engine in great detail. You'll learn much more then what someone will be willing to post here on stack. Tile Engines as you will see from this tutorial, requires more then just a few lines of code. After you learn it here, it shouldn't be to hard for you to translate it to sdl/c++. Just a thought.

Its a good starting place.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check this out.